# Search controller in parent view controller blocks modals from being presented

Tags: ios, swift

Using a search controller and presenting search results does not allow any modals to be presented in child view controllers.  I have a work around using multiple delegates calling up the stack to disable search controller when its active.

This happens when I try to pop up an alert or present an image picker view.

delegate method example:

```
func cancelSearch() {
    if(self.searchController.isActive == true){
        self.searchController.isActive = false
    }
}
```

I would like to find a universal call to disable any search controllers up the stack of parent VCs.

I wish this didn't need to be done at all because when going back to the parent VC the search results are now gone and it is hard to predict when this issue will occur.

Comment: A search controller _is_ a presented view controller. So now your view controller is already presenting a view controller. It cannot present _two_ view controllers; a view controller can present only one view controller. If you need to present something else, you can tell the search controller to present it, or you can dismiss the search controller first.

Comment: By the way, _never_ say `== true` in a condition. The Bool _is_ a Bool, it is already usable as a condition. And stop using parentheses! This is not C. So just say `if self.searchController.isActive`.

Comment: Ok thanks,  I just do this from old habit I guess.  I have had some issues where not asking if its "true" yields unexpected results, like when a var is instantiated it returns a true condition even if it's value is "false".  Maybe thats not the case with Bools.  Thanks again

Comment: Only a Bool can be used in a Swift condition so the issue doesn't arise. You seem to be still thinking like an Objective-C programmer!